# Test question regarding botany

Tags: botany

I'm having a hard time understanding what exactly those letters and numbers in the task in the photo below represent, also the task says "Is the blossom formula written correctly?" translated from Lithuanian to English. I would appreciate some guidance.

[image: **enter image description here**]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are [floral formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floral_formula), a way to succinctly describe how many petals/sepals/pistils/... the flower contains, and their relations (free, fused, ...). The wikipedia page describe the meaning of each symbol.

For example, for the first one :

- Up arrow : symmetry along the vertical axis
- K(6) : 6 sepals (K), which are joined (parenthesis)
- C(2.3) : Two large petals, three smaller, joined. (not sure on the exact signification of 2.3)
- A2 : Two stamen, not joined
- [C(2.3) A2] : the petals and stamen are fused
- G(2) : two fused carpels

Continuing with that example, it seems to me the first formula is not correct given the schematics below : there are 4 carpels. Though I'm no botanist.